# Custom Actionbar tab view ignoring layout_gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm looking to override the tab style on a tab-by-tab basis, so that I can apply an effect to certain tabs while leaving others normal.

Here is the layout XML I'm using for my custom tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CustomActionBarTabTextStyle"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Following the implementation in update() in com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView.TabView is have set the layout params and text ellipse accordingly. The only thing my CustomActionBarTabTextStyle overrides currently is the text size.

The tabs to be rendering exactly as they would without the custom view except that the text is top-aligned within the tab. A quick run in hierarchy viewer shows that layout_gravity is showing as NONE, whereas layout_gravity is CENTER_VERTICAL for non-custom tabs. How is this possible? Does anyone have a way to fix this? I've tried putting android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" in styles and themes all over the place with no results.

Answer (score 2):

I have a working solution now, but it's not very pretty. I have to create and set my LayoutParams explicitly when I set the custom view.

```
tab.setCustomView(customtabviewresourceid);
TextView tv = ((TextView)tab.getCustomView());
tv.setText(tab.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity=Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

I'm still looking for answers because I don't think this is the best way. Ideally this should not be done in Java code.